# Access report building for Dummies

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a database that tracks invoice payment certification. I am trying to build a report that will bring The following info in

```
Service Line - ABC
Total "unique" records - 2
max age - 3
Min age - 1
Avg of max age - 3
count of records over 14 days - 0
count of records under 14 days - 2
score: records under 14 days/total records - 100%
```

I am trying to build the report from a query that includes a date range. the important column names are:

```
Service Line              DLN                Age in days
ABC                     123456                    1
DEF                     987654                    3
ABC                     123456                    2
DEF                     987654                    4
ABC                     123456                    3
```

The DLN is an identifier to each different invoice number. I entered the data in above that I need it to return as it correlates to the table below.

Comment: The sample data is helpful, but more is needed to help you. [For example, do you know about grouping on a report?] Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I totally forgot I asked the question on here and ended up fixing the issue. What I ended up doing is building the report from scratch from the query instead of using the wizard. Then I just free typed the functions into unbound text boxes. I did then use the grouping to separate it the way I needed. Once I realized my mistake and that the solution was so easy I felt kind of dumb.